# Minimum sum from a subsequence

Tags: number-theory, arithmetic

We are given a sequence of numbers. We have to divide that sequence into $ k $ contigous sequence. And let sum of $i $ th patition would be $S_i$. Then we have to divide the sequence such that value of $T = S_1^2 + S_2^2 + \cdots + S_k^2 $ is minimum. Then how can we find minimum vaue of $T$ .

I thought of sorting the array the divide into $k $ parts.

Am I correct?

Can anybody please help me in this?

Answer (score 0):

Using Cauchy-Schwarz inequality: $T \ge \dfrac{(S_1+S_2+...+S_k)^2}{k} = \dfrac{(a_1+a_2+...+a_n)^2}{k}= T_{\text{min}}$

Comment: If k does not divide it perfectly.

Comment: Let sequence be 15, 5, 15 and K = 2

Comment: Then answer should be 625.

Comment: @jsav Please add your example to ypur post

Comment: This looks like a programming question that is supposed to find the minumum for a given sequence, which will usually not be the optimal value if Cauchy-Schwarz.

Comment: @jsav: Sequence $15,5,15$ and $K=2$ is trivial, you only have 2 options, you can insert the "divider" betweeen first and second subsequence either before or after the $5$. In both cases, one subsequence contains just 15, the other 15 and 5 (it just changes which is the first and second subsequence). So one of your sums is 15+5=20 and the other is 15, so $S_1^2+S_2^2=20^2+15^2=400+225=625$.